# Dynamically added tablerow only last row not visible

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I have created a tablelayout with the header row added in the XML file and the remaining content rows filled in dynamically.
For some reason, the last row is not visible.
I looked through other related posts and everything seems okay in my code.
Appreciate if someone could take a look and point out the problem.

XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.bluechipsys.mcpackagemanager.PMActivity"
    android:id="@+id/view_layout">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/installProgressBar"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Large"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ProgressBar>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/textAreaScroller"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_reload"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:singleLine="false">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/msg_default"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/viewLog"
        android:maxLines="1000"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/versionInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableLayoutScroller"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tableLayoutScroller"
        android:text="@string/tv_versioninfo"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/tableLayoutScroller"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="@+id/textAreaScroller"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textAreaScroller"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textAreaScroller"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textAreaScroller"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/tbl_packagelist"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="@+id/textAreaScroller"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textAreaScroller"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textAreaScroller"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textAreaScroller"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:stretchColumns="1,2,3,4,5"
        android:shrinkColumns="2"
        android:background="@drawable/border_table">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbSelect"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/title_cell_shape"
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:id="@+id/tvState"
                android:background="@drawable/title_cell_shape"
                android:editable="false" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/tv_package"
                android:id="@+id/tvPackage"
                android:background="@drawable/title_cell_shape"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="fill"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/tv_instver"
                android:id="@+id/tvInstver"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:background="@drawable/title_cell_shape"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="fill"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/tv_latestver"
                android:id="@+id/tvLatestver"
                android:background="@drawable/title_cell_shape"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="fill"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/tv_size"
                android:id="@+id/tvSize"
                android:background="@drawable/title_cell_shape"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="fill"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_reload"
        android:id="@+id/btn_reload"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/reload"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_apply"
        android:id="@+id/btn_apply"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/apply"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_reload"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_close"
        android:id="@+id/btn_close"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/close"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_reload"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textAreaScroller"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textAreaScroller" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
private void clearTableRows() {
        Logger.d(TAG, "Clearing table rows");

        TableLayout main_table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl_packagelist);
        int rowCount = main_table.getChildCount();
        main_table.removeViews(1, rowCount - 1);    // Leave header row intact
    }

    // Create table rows and add to the GUI
    private void createTableRows() {
        Logger.d(TAG, "Creating table rows");

        final TableLayout main_table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl_packagelist);
        Drawable background;

        // Define layout parameters
        TableLayout.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TableRow.LayoutParams itemCBParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TableRow.LayoutParams itemIVParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        itemIVParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;      // Centre the image display
        TableRow.LayoutParams itemParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mLayoutItemParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams (itemParams);
        MarginLayoutParamsCompat.setMarginStart(mLayoutItemParams, 4);  // Need this workaround for API level < 17

        for (MCPackage pkg: list_packages) {
            // Create the TableRow and widgets to add to the TableRow
            TableRow tbl_row = new TableRow(this);
            CheckBox cb_select = new CheckBox(this);
            ImageView iv_state = new ImageView(this);
            TextView tv_package = new TextView(this);
            TextView tv_instver = new TextView(this);
            TextView tv_currver = new TextView(this);
            TextView tv_pkgsize = new TextView(this);

            int index = list_packages.indexOf(pkg);
            if(index % 2 == 0) {
                background = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cell_shape_white);
            } else {
                background = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cell_shape_grey);
            }

            // Set GUI parameters for the TableRow
            tbl_row.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
            tbl_row.setBackground(background);
            tbl_row.setId(index);           // Set ID to match index of list_packages

            // Initialize the cells
            cb_select.setLayoutParams(itemCBParams);
            cb_select.setId(index + CHECKBOX_ID);
            cb_ids[index] = (index + CHECKBOX_ID);
            cb_select.setOnClickListener(checkboxOnClick());
            cb_select.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkboxOnCheckChange());

            iv_state.setLayoutParams(itemIVParams);
            iv_state.setImageResource(pkg.getState().getImageResourceId());
            iv_state.setId(index + IVSTATE_ID);
            iv_state_ids[index] = (index + IVSTATE_ID);

            tv_package.setLayoutParams(itemParams);
            tv_package.setText(pkg.getPackageName());
            tv_package.setGravity(Gravity.FILL);
            tv_package.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small);
            tv_package.setTextSize(12);
            tv_package.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            tv_package.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

            tv_instver.setLayoutParams(itemParams);
            tv_instver.setText(pkg.getInstalledVersion());
            tv_instver.setGravity(Gravity.FILL);
            tv_instver.setTextSize(12);
            tv_instver.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            tv_instver.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

            tv_currver.setLayoutParams(itemParams);
            tv_currver.setText(pkg.getUpdateVersion());
            tv_currver.setGravity(Gravity.FILL);
            tv_currver.setTextSize(12);
            tv_currver.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            tv_currver.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

            tv_pkgsize.setLayoutParams(itemParams);
            tv_pkgsize.setText(String.valueOf(((int) pkg.getPackageSize()) / KBINBYTES) + "K");
            tv_pkgsize.setGravity(Gravity.FILL);
            tv_pkgsize.setTextSize(12);
            tv_pkgsize.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            tv_pkgsize.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

            // Add the cells to the row
            tbl_row.addView(cb_select);
            tbl_row.addView(iv_state);
            tbl_row.addView(tv_package);
            tbl_row.addView(tv_instver);
            tbl_row.addView(tv_currver);
            tbl_row.addView(tv_pkgsize);

            main_table.addView(tbl_row);        // Add the row to the table
            tbl_row.setOnClickListener(rowClickListener);
            tbl_row.setOnLongClickListener(rowLongClickListener);
            registerForContextMenu(tbl_row);    // Register the table row for context menu
            Logger.d(TAG, "Added package: " + pkg.getPackageName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: For starters I'd change the height on the table row TextView(s) to wrap_content, they are set to match the parent, but the parent is set to wrap content.

Comment: Tried using wrap_content: TableRow.LayoutParams itemParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
Didn't help though.

Comment: It is just the pkgsize row you don't see?  Is it a scroll issue, does the both scroll views work?  Have you tried dumping the screen and viewing the the XML data in DDMS?

Comment: Yes, just the last row.
The scrollviews scroll okay. 
Even after I sort the packageName column, it gets sorted alphabetically, but the new last row cannot be seen.
It does get added based on the print log, but can't see it in the GUI.

Comment: @rogger did you find answer for the problem?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it is still a problem, but try to use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`.